# What does >& do?

Tags: bash, jenkins, io-redirection

I have a command in a makefile for a project I am working on and I have no idea what the `>&` part in `java -jar java-cup-11a.jar -parser  mj -dump src/mjparser/mj.cup >& javacup.dump` does.

The bash documentation says that is illegal (and so does my jenkins when I tried to automate this) but for some reason building on the work machines, this command is perfectly legal and only works this way. I have tried changing it to `>&1` to make it a valid redirect but it breaks the command and it can't handle it.

Should the make command be changed to have surrounding quotes to allow it to execute as a single command? Why is my Jenkins treating this command differently than a similar environment?

Comment: Have a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/335396/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>&` is a [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism).

It redirects both the `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

An equivalent to what you're using would be:

```
java -jar java-cup-11a.jar -parser mj -dump src/mjparser/mj.cup > javacup.dump 2>&1
```

which would work in `sh` and `dash` as well.

Comment: @Mithrandir Unfortunately, SO doesn't allow `/` in usernames.

Comment: It just seems so fitting for the question. Quite impressive you scored it.